# What's a good intro book to stochastic processes?

Tags: reference-request, stochastic-processes

I'm taking stochastic processes now (I'm an undergrad math major), and feel the book we're using is inadequate and lacks detail. Here is a link to the book: [http://www.amazon.com/dp/0123756863/ref=rdr_ext_sb_ti_sims_4](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0123756863)

Any suggestions for a good intro book? I want to understand the concepts, and feel this book isn't working.

Thanks.

Comment: You might want to look at this posting http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/283539/what-is-more-elementary-than-introduction-to-stochastic-processes-by-lawler Regards